# PreSign URL when using VersionID in key params does not work

Tags: amazon-s3, signing, aws-sdk-nodejs

I can not seem to send a VersionID param along with my Key when using getSignUrl according to NodeJS S3 SDK Docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property)

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key?versionId=someversion'};
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
  console.log('The URL is', url);
});
```

[image: NodeJS SDK S3 getSignedUrl at the time of posting]

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble finding it documented anywhere and ended up guessing around a bit but this ended up working. (Not sure why it is undocumented...)

Added `VersionId` params to `getSigneUrl` call:

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', VersionId: 'someversion'};
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
  console.log('The URL is', url);
});
```